Could Twitter have banned trump even if they didn't have ToS?
could Twitter have banned Trump even if they had no ToS?
From this article: (1)

Violations of such terms and conditions agreements recently gave Amazon the power to block the right-leaning social media site Parler and for Twitter to ban Donald Trump

That makes it seem like Twitter needed to have a ToS to allow them to ban him. But ToS is not required, right?
(1): https://www.nytimes.com/2021/01/23/opinion/sunday/online-terms-of-service.html

As a private entity, would Twitter/X need an explicit TOS to govern their actions? A TOS makes actions/consequences clear and Amazon sited their TOS but that could just be a CYA document.

If there were no Terms of Service agreement, then the legal question would be what rights someone has as a implied contractual term in the absence of an agreement. In all likelihood, it would have prevailed anyway.
But the TOS approach avoids having to consider the default rules of law and is supported by more case law (and the TOS is also needed for unrelated purposes), so the TOS reduces litigation cost and risk even though the ultimate outcome is very likely to be the same.

The TOS also doesn't limit Twitter's actions. They don't have to enumerate all the bad behaviors that can get you banned. It's more like a warning: "If you do this and we catch you, we're likely to take such-and-such action."
